# Force file download from specific directory .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, http-headers

So I found the following which will force an image to download instead of open in the browser

```
<FilesMatch "\.(jpg)$">
Header set Content-Type application/octet-stream
Header set Content-Disposition attachment
</FilesMatch>
```

Is there a way to apply this only to one directory? I tried

```
<FilesMatch "wallpaper\.(jpg)$">
```

With no luck. Basically I only want files in that specific folder (not subdirectories) to force a download if someone browses to it.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried this, but I think you could use a `Directory` directive in your `.htaccess` file to accomplish this:

```
<Directory "wallpapers">
  <FilesMatch "\.(jpg)$">
  Header set Content-Type application/octet-stream
  Header set Content-Disposition attachment
  </FilesMatch>
</Directory>
```

From the [`documentation`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#directory):

> < Directory > and < Directory/ > are used to enclose a group of directives
>       that will apply only to the named directory, sub-directories of that
>       directory, and the files within the respective directories.